# ASP.NET Web forms auto encode value in hidden field (against xss?) when received it from server

Tags: asp.net, encoding, webforms, escaping, xss

I maintain a web forms app and don't understand next behavior:
i have the hidden field in the Web form:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenJson" />
```

On the serverside, i use the next code for transferring json into hidden field: (example):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lists = new List<TestDto>();
            lists.Add(new TestDto()
            {
                Name = "<script>alert(1)</script>",
                Middle = "<html></html>",
                LastName = "2222"
            });
            lists.Add(new TestDto()
            {
                Name = "<script>alert(2)</script>",
                Middle = "<html></html>",
                LastName = "2222"
            });
            lists.Add(new TestDto()
            {
                Name = "<script>alert(3)</script>",
                Middle = "<html></html>",
                LastName = "2222"
            });
            lists.Add(new TestDto()
            {
                Name = "<script>alert(4)</script>",
                Middle = "<html></html>",
                LastName = "2222"
            });

            HiddenJson.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lists, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
            });
        }
```

It is working good, but string in hiddenfield value has encoded, like

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$HiddenJsonInfo" id="MainContent_HiddenJsonInfo" value="
[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;&lt;script>alert(1)&lt;/script>&quot;,&quot;Middle&quot;:&quot;&lt;html>&lt;/html>&quot;,&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;2222&quot;},{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;&lt;script>alert(2)&lt;/script>&quot;,&quot;Middle&quot;:&quot;&lt;html>&lt;/html>&quot;,&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;2222&quot;},{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;&lt;script>alert(3)&lt;/script>&quot;,&quot;Middle&quot;:&quot;&lt;html>&lt;/html>&quot;,&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;2222&quot;},{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;&lt;script>alert(4)&lt;/script>&quot;,&quot;Middle&quot;:&quot;&lt;html>&lt;/html>&quot;,&quot;LastName&quot;:&quot;2222&quot;}]" />
```

1. Is it auto behavior?
2. Why my string has encoded?
3. What component or mechanism does that?
4. Can I change this behavior?
5. Is it safe or not?

Comment: This does sound like it would be default behavior as a measure against XSS and such.  Before attempting to change this behavior, it would be prudent to first define *why* you want to change this behavior.  Is this causing a problem of any kind?  Might that problem have a solution that doesn't involve potentially exposing XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: @David, Yes, I know, just scientific interest (about change behavior):) I want to understand, what part of ASP NET web forms do these things (maybe, when make some actions with ViewState (before serialized?))

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is escaping your text.

Comment: No.I tried to transfer JsonConvert.SerializeObject on the form in server tags. It is not encoding. But, if i add settings (StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml), JsonConvert.SerializeObject can encode symbols to unicode codes. In my case, I have escaping: &lt;, &gt; and etc., but not unicode codes. (And, if you look in debug mode, after JsonConvert.SerializeObject,, you will see, that result contains not encoded symbols.